# How to write conditional statement for date input value?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make an `if` conditional for a specific day in date picker?
For example, when the user inserts a specific day in date picker, a message appears and reports whether events exist.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x, text;
  // Get the value of input field with id="test"
  x = document.getElementById("test").value;
  if (x == "07/21/2019") {
    text = "Birthday event";
  } else {
    text = "No events";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>make if conditional for a specific day in datepicker</p> <input id="test" type="date"> <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You need to have some data with the events, and you need to get the relevant data through JavaScript then. But without seeing more more of your code and your setup, its really hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The date value is in the format:

> yyyy-mm-dd

See [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the actual value — the displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's browser, whereas the date value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x, text;
  // Get the value of input field with id="test"
  x = document.getElementById("test").value;
  console.log(x);
  if (x == "2017-07-21") {
    text = "Birthday event";
  } else {
    text = "No events";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>make if conditional for a specific day in datepicker</p>
<input id="test" type="date" value="2017-07-21">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Also see [Date and time formats used in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#Examples)
.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to have the selected date retrieved from a date picker and an array of dates you have events. Then you have to do a comparison between them.

Here is the HTML code where the Date Picker is displayed.

```
Select a day : <input type="date" id="selectedDate">
<button onclick="checkEventDate()"> Check Events</button>
```

This is the JavaScript function

```
function checkEventDate() {
    //Get the date selected from the Date Picker and convert it to a Date Object
    var selectedDate = new Date(document.getElementById("selectedDate").value);

    //Convert the Date Object to a DateSrting.
    var isSelectedDate = selectedDate.toDateString();

    // Let's assume you have an array of dates which have events 
    var eventDates = ["2019-07-07", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09"];

    for (var i = 0; i < eventDates.length; i++) {
        //Convert each value in the dates array to a Date Object
        eventDate = new Date(eventDates[i])

        //Convert every Date Object to a DateString type
        iseventDate = eventDate.toDateString();

        //Now compare if the selected date is a event date
        if (iseventDate == isSelectedDate) {
            alert("There is an event on the selected date.");
        }
    }
}
```